# how to disable logging in Process monitor while startup

Tags: windows, sysinternals, procmon, process-monitor

How to Open Process monitor with logging on all logging components STOPPED.

By default, it starts capturing all the logs giving no time to do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> which stops Capture Events and apply my filter.

It fills virtual memory quick enough to become 'not responding'.

I am interested in File I/O logging to a specific path using Filters, but process monitor hangs due to the log that grows with components that am not interested.

I am not finding any answers related to startup of process monitor.

Comment: This question seems more suitable for superuser

Comment: @Samantha but its a tool commonly used by programmers while debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `/noconnect` command-line switch, i.e. run `procmon.exe /noconnect`.